# Protractor: how to catch error or timeout on browser.driver.get(url) if remote url is fail to load?

Tags: protractor, jasmine-node

It seems when protractor execute "browser.driver.get(...)" it waits until page is loaded or throw "`Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`" message. Remote url is 1 to 10 times fail to load (following by freeze). A workaround for that is to refresh/reload page. Is there any way to implement that behaviour in Protractor? (let say repeat action 4-8 times and then continue)

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to catch errors thrown through the promises api, like this:

```
browser.driver.get(...).then(function(result) {
  // do something when page is found
}.thenCatch(function(error) {
  // do something with the error
});
```

Comment: It prints {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending" } has no method 'catch'

Comment: Oops. I think the correct method is `thenCatch`. Changed the answer.

Comment: I'm still getting error: "Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL" and then protractor exists. Callback on "thenCatch" never calls.